# Magento Price Including VAT Not Working

Tags: catalog, tax

I have entered the product price excluding VAT in the backend.

In the TAX configuration, setting is

`Display Product Prices In Catalog set as Including Tax`.

In the product page, product price and special price is getting displayed with including 20%VAT.

But the featured products in the home page displaying the price with excluding VAT. I have used the code for featured products,

```
echo Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getPrice(), true);
echo Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getFinalPrice(), true);
```

Both returning the price excluding the VAT. Products in the home page needs to return price including VAT.  Could anyone help on this?

Answer (score 1):

Please use a block for the price and use the getPriceHtml methods.

See this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652808/magento-using-this-getpricehtml-on-custom-page-template

Comment: Even if I use, getPriceHtml method, price excluding VAT is getting displayed.

Comment: @blakcaps same here. Did you fix this? All settings for tax in the backend is set to display tax inclusive.